# Assign unique ID based on match between two columns in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to assign an auto incremental unique ID to a column in the dataframe.

If the column1 value is a match with column2 value flag will be enabled as true and for all those matches we need to assign a same ID. If there is no match of column1 value with column2 value flag will be False and we need to provide a unique ID for that column1 value.

**Input df**

| ID | Column1 | Column2 | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 1 | 2 | True |
| null | 1 | 3 | True |
| null | 2 | 1 | True |
| null | 2 | 3 | True |
| null | 3 | 1 | True |
| null | 3 | 2 | True |
| null | 4 |  | False |
| null | 5 |  | False |
| null | 6 | 7 | True |
| null | 7 | 6 | True |
| null | 9 | 2 | True |
| null | 1 | 9 | True |
| null | 3 | 9 | True |
| null | 2 | 9 | True |
| null | 8 |  | False |

**Output df**

Here column1 value 1,2,3 and 9 form a match so we assign a single unique ID for all these 4 values(101), column1 value 4 is not a match so we assign next unique ID(102), column1 value 5 is also not a match so we assign next unique ID(103), column1 value 6 and 7 are matches so we assign same unique ID for 2 values(104), column1 value 8 is not a match with any of column2 value so we assign next unique ID 105

| ID | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 102 | 4 |
| 103 | 5 |
| 104 | 6 |
| 104 | 7 |
| 101 | 9 |
| 105 | 8 |

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for every unique value in `col1`, you need to check if that value exists in `col2`, if yes then `flag` is True, otherwise `flag` is False? How can you "group" 1, 2, 3, 9 together, or 6, 7?

Comment: Hi @pltc, Yes col1 values are unique in the output df. In input each col1 value is mapped to a col2 value and it indicates that those two values share an unique ID. Here in first row 1 is mapped to 2, so 1 and 2 form a pair and will have same ID(101) assigned to both. In 2nd row, 1 is again mapped to 3 so now 3 also shares the same ID(101) along with 1 and 2. In 3rd row, 2 is mapped with 1 and we already identified unique ID for this pair. It continues.. and in 11th row 9 of col1 is mapped to 2 of col2 so 9 also should share same ID(101) along with 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my explanation in the code. Just be careful about using `Window` without partition your data, this operation will move all of your data to a single node.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# [...] Your dataframe initialization

# Creating an index to retrieve original dataframe at the end
df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

w = Window.orderBy('least')

# Creating a column with least value from `Column1` and `Column2`. This will be used to "group" the values that must have the same ID
df = df.withColumn('least', f.least(f.col('Column1'), f.col('Column2')))

# Check if the current or previous `flag` is false to increase the id
df = df.withColumn('increase', ((~f.col('flag')) | (~f.lag('flag', default=True).over(w))).cast('int'))

# Generating incremental id
df = df.withColumn('ID', f.lit(101) + f.sum('increase').over(w))

(df
 .select('ID', 'Column1')
 .drop_duplicates()
 .sort('index')
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Output

```
+---+-------+
|ID |Column1|
+---+-------+
|101|1      |
|101|2      |
|101|3      |
|102|4      |
|103|5      |
|104|6      |
|104|7      |
|101|9      |
|105|8      |
+---+-------+
```

Comment: Hi @Kafels, Thanks for your answer, the values in column1 will not be in order so we need to consider all the matches for a number in column2 and then assign a unique ID for that group. I have edited my question

Comment: @jvr I did an update. I couldn't figure out a manner to achieve your result without sorting the dataframe. Check if it solves your problem